# A frase "Homens que invadiram café da esquina contratados pela seguradora" está formalmente correta?

Tags: gramática, formalismo

Esta frase deve ser entendida como um título de uma notícia.

Apesar de se conseguir escrever de uma forma menos confusa, a questão prende-se com o facto de se encontrar ou não formalmente correta e se a seguinte frase seria uma melhor solução:

"Homens, que invadiram o café da esquina, foram contratados pela seguradora"

Comment: A segunda frase, defenitivamente; possivelmente sem vírgulas.

Comment: A falta do verbo deixa a frase bem estranha mesmo. Jornalistas às vezes improvisam para economizar espaço, e nem sempre dá certo...

Comment: Outra opção seria: "Seguradora contrata homens que invadiram café da esquina"

Answer (score 3):

## Não

A frase possui predicado sem verbo, [o que vai contra a definição de uma oração que possui sujeito](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint10.php), no caso, "Homens".